# How to create UI in angular to display m by n matrix and what should be the json format?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, user-interface

[image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6jhQ.png)

the matrix would be m by n having names on left and top of the matrix
note: must have column and row name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to use bootstrap grid.Here what I've done for you

You can change the colors as you wish

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-f7pdg5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
check out my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwmm8u)